# How to Treat "null" Values in JSON file as null with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, null

I have a large JSON file that is generated by another process that I can't modify. In case of blank values, that process puts "null" as a value of those properties.

And I need to treat these "null" values as null in my **Nodejs** server side, or else they are taken as literal string. I would like to see if there is a way with `JSON.parser(fs.readFileSync('...'))` to read the file and create a local variable that has `null` instead of `"null"` for those properties.

Comment: Why not fix the generation and make it behave correctly? People with the last name "Null" already have enough problems and don't need another application treating them as if they don't exist. Or a user typing "null" intentionally breaking an application. Or any other number of things that result in "null" as a legitimate string that will then cause obscure hard to track down and harder to fix bugs to crop up.

Comment: As I said, I don't have access to it. Besides, it's going to affect many other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of achieving this is using the `reviver` function as per the JSON.parse() [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter):

```
let json = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "null"}';

let obj = JSON.parse(json, function reviver(key, value) {
  return (value == 'null') ? null : value;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43740478/3107689) answer.

Instead of replacing it with text, replace `'null'` with `null`.

so:

```
// test.json content:
{
    "test": "null",
    "test2": "null",
    "test3": null,
    "test4": [1, null, "null", 2, "3"]
}


// index.js content:
const fs = require('fs');

const source = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');
const fixedJson = source.replace(/"null"/g, 'null');
const fixedObject = JSON.parse(fixedJson);

console.log(fixedJson);
console.log(fixedObject);
console.log(fixedObject.test3 === null);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I still get `"null"` value back.

Comment: No, you will get `null`, not `'null'`. That what you asked for. What else do you want to get?

Comment: You ask for `null` in Node variable. In case you want to get `''` in the variable, change the second argument of the replace to `''`.

Comment: When I say `null`, the outcome should be like `{ "test": null}`. I want to be able to iterate through the properties and match against null, e.g. `if (test === null)`.

Comment: Great, so please accept my answer, because `fixedObject.test === null` will result to `true`. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested this to see if you can read the JSON from a fall (as the description reads), replace those null values, then parse it back to that same variable, then use it for testing? I don't seem to be able to get this working (Nodejs server side).

Comment: Did you test it? Anyway, please post the file content for example.

Comment: The old replace function worked only for the first occurrence, check the fixed answer. Be aware @vlaz comment. If any key is "null" you will get an error at `JSON.parse`